# How can dot in ieee style citations be removed?

Tags: biblatex, citing, ieee-style

I'm using ieee style citation with biblatex but every time I cite a reference it puts a full stop after the number, e.g. [1.], and  [25.]

How can I remove the full stop inside the square brackets? Does anyone have an idea? It's for my Thesis,  which I have to submit on Friday.

Comment: I don't think this should happen and in a simple example document it does not happen (see https://gist.github.com/moewew/a901096d75b14b452a63ac8e0407d3c1). So there must be some code specific to your document that causes this output. I'm afraid you will have to show us a small example document that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.

Comment: @moewe it was my own fault, I already posted the solution to my problem below. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, it was my own mistake. I wanted to make my citations in bold and found another answer in which they had added a dot with `\addot` in the lines I used in the preamble. So to make the citations in bold and with a dot I used:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}\adddot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}\adddot}
```

And all I had to do was remove the `\dot` so the citations would only be in bold without a dot:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{prefixnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
```